# WordPress alternate post styling with bootstrap col-offset using Custom Content Shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to style the post in the loop in alternate styling using Custom Content Short code plugin. Some what like this.

[Example image of post styling using bootstrap col-offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9LJN.png)

This is what i'm trying

```
<?php start_short(); ?>
    [loop type=service orderby=date order=ASC]
    <div class="jumbo" style="background-image: url([field image-url]);">
        <div class="blackBG row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-7 BGdark opaque page-block-full wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="0.40s" data-wow-delay="0.50s">
                <h1><b class="square BGsec">1</b><small>[field title]</small></h1>
                <p>[content more=true more=... length=200]</p>
                <a class="btn btn-default light" href="[field url]" title="DUX Technology - [field title]">Check Now <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    [/loop]
    <?php end_short(); ?>
```

What I want to display is:

```
    <div class="jumbo" style="background-image: url([field image-url]);">
        <div class="blackBG row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-7 BGdark opaque page-block-full wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="0.40s" data-wow-delay="0.50s">
                <h1><b class="square BGsec">1</b><small>[field title]</small></h1>
                <p>[content more=true more=... length=200]</p>
                <a class="btn btn-default light" href="[field url]" title="DUX Technology - [field title]">Check Now <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbo" style="background-image: url([field image-url]);">
        <div class="blackBG row">
            <div class="col-md-5 BGdark opaque page-block-full wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="0.40s" data-wow-delay="0.50s">
                <h1><b class="square BGsec">1</b><small>[field title]</small></h1>
                <p>[content more=true more=... length=200]</p>
                <a class="btn btn-default light" href="[field url]" title="DUX Technology - [field title]">Check Now <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbo" style="background-image: url([field image-url]);">
        <div class="blackBG row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-7 BGdark opaque page-block-full wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="0.40s" data-wow-delay="0.50s">
                <h1><b class="square BGsec">1</b><small>[field title]</small></h1>
                <p>[content more=true more=... length=200]</p>
                <a class="btn btn-default light" href="[field url]" title="DUX Technology - [field title]">Check Now <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The above code was generating a loop of post in WordPress with single class of col-md-offset-7 to every post.

What I did was use jQuery even function to delete class from alternate post.

```
$("div.service-post:even").removeClass("col-md-offset-7");
```